# Ways to include time in hierarchical mixed effects model

Tags: bayesian, mixed-model, hierarchical-bayesian, time-varying-covariate

My colleagues and I have been using a hierarchical mixed model that so far has provided good predictions. As time goes on, however, it's clear that not including time as a factor in the model degrades predictions. For clusters within the data it is reasonable to assume that the distribution of the outcome variable will change over time. In its current, time-oblivious form, the model accounts for these changes fairly slowly, since past (sometimes quite old) observations paint a different picture than more recent observations.

**How can such a model "put more weight" on more recent observations?**

I'll briefly sketch out the problem I'm specifically working on, but I hope to keep the question general enough that it can be relevant to others.

## Problem background

I'm modeling sales events for limited edition products. Each observation in my data set is one such event where a single product is sold, with features describing the event itself (e.g. the region it took place in, the date of the event) and the product (e.g. product group, product model within group, price, etc.).

The model is built to predict the expected consumer demand (i.e. how many people will show interest) for a future event given the above features about the event and product. This demand is observed for historical observations.

There are hierarchical structures in the data that the model intends to capture:

- a **product group** (e.g. footwear) can include various **product models**. Each **product model** within the same group shares similarities (use-case, potential materials, price range, etc. ) with other models in its group.
- there are multiple products of the same **product model**, these share things like a general design theme, product features etc. but each represent a different 'take' on the model by different designers.
- the **regions** where these events take place differ in unobserved social, economic and cultural factors, but likely share some global effects.

## Time oblivious model

I currently have a hierarchical mixed effects model  that includes a hierarchical intercept $L$ with three levels:

- $\mathrm{L1}$ is the intercept for observations in different regions ($a$)
- $\mathrm{L2}$ is the intercept for observations of different product groups ($b$) per region ($a$)
- $\mathrm{L3}$ is the intercept for observations of different product models ($c$) of different product groups ($b$) per region ($a$)

The idea behind this structure is the following: it could be that a product model has not been sold in a particular region before, in which case the intercept should be informed by events for products from the same product group in that region.

$$
\alpha \sim \mathcal{N}(5, 1)\\
\mathrm{L1}_{a_i} \sim \mathcal{N}(\alpha, 1)\\
\mathrm{L2}_{a_i, b_i} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathrm{L1}_{a_i}, 1)\\
\mathrm{L3}_{a_i, b_i, c_i} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathrm{L2}_{a_i, b_i}, 1)\\
\mu_i = \mathrm{L3}_{a_i, b_i, c_i} + \beta_1 \mathbf{X}_{i,1} + \cdots +\beta_k \mathbf{X}_{i,k} \\
\cdots \\
\sigma \sim Exp(1)\\
y_i \sim \mathrm{StudentT}(\mu_i, \sigma, \nu)\\
$$

where

- $a_i$ is the region of the i-th event in the data
- $b_i$ and $c_i$ are the product group and product model of the i-th observation, respectively
- $\mathbf{X}_{i,1}$ to $\mathbf{X}_{i,k}$ are other features related to the i-th observation

There are also some varying slope terms in the model that vary by some of the groups mentioned here, but I've excluded them to not make things confusing.

As you can see, **this model does not include time at all**. The intercept for a product model $c_3$ for example is equally informed by an event where a product of this model was sold 4 years ago and one that happened just yesterday. My experience tells me that this is problematically ignorant, so I want to change that.

## Approaches I considered

1. **Time as a fixed or varying effect:** I could capture time as a continuous variable $t$ (0 for the first observation, 1 for the last historic observation, >1 for future events) and include a fixed or varying effect for it into the linear model of $\mu$.
2. **Interaction with time:** as an extension of the above point, interactions between $t$ and other terms in the model could be introduced.
3. **GP prior for the intercept:** I'm not really familiar with Gaussian processes, but I'd assume a GP over $t$ could be used to model the intercept
4. **Intercept level for units of time:** an additonal level could be added to the intercept to model the average demand in a particular unit of time, for example a given year. Since this will increase the already large dimensionality of the intercept even more, I'm worried that this will be problematic.

**Am I missing any approaches? How can I determine which approach I should use?**